# How to pass arguments between two windows in html[ Values between parent and child window]

Tags: javascript

Description :
I am using java script
I cannot retrieve using dom object.

Comment: Explain more. What you want? what you tried? what you researched?

Comment: Hello  Friend I understand as per my knowledge you are trying to pass values between a parent window and a child window. If that is the case i know a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this
At first retrieving value from a parent window 
will be using

```
 If you open child using
    popupWindow = window.open("my.html",'some name','width=500,height=500');

            In Child window:


                //This gives DOM value of parent in child window.
                    window.opener.document.getElementById("your field name in parent window");



        //setting value
        window.opener['dataitem'] = document.getElementById("your field name in child window").value;
```

In parent window:

```
                 //This gives DOM value of child in parent window.
                var some_data = window['dataitem'];
```

Hope this helps you!! 
Thank you ..